# Android upload JSON to server error

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to upload a JSON file to my server which is using PHP. But the response is always false and I don't know why. I have tried to switch the order of information but it didn't help.

Here is the code of my method:

```
public void uploadJSON(){
    try {
        JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
        toSend.put("user", "guri1");
        toSend.put("ts", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        toSend.put("lat", 35.45);
        toSend.put("lon", 48.4);
        toSend.put("text", "Toto som poslal");
        toSend.put("tags", "");
        toSend.put("img", "");
        JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
        transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[] {toSend});

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

JSONTransmitter is basically an asynctask. Here is the code for it:

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

String url = "MYURLISHERE";

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
    JSONObject json = data[0];
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response;
        response = client.execute(post);
        String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


        Log.i("Response from server", resFromServer);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

And here is the php:

```
function postevent(){
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$ts=$data["ts"]*1;
$lat=$data["lat"]*1;
$lon=$data["lon"]*1;
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($data["user"]);
$text=mysql_real_escape_string($data["text"]);
$tags=mysql_real_escape_string($data["tags"]); 
$img=mysql_real_escape_string($data["img"]);
if ($user!=""){
$result=db_query("INSERT INTO events SET ts='$ts',lat='$lat',lon='$lon',user='$user',text='$text',tags='$tags',img='$img'");
} else { $result=FALSE; }
if($result==FALSE){
echo "false";
} else {
echo "true";
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like the error happens in the server side. You need to narrow down which causes it: that $user is empty or db_query failed ?

Comment: well I don't know. But are you sure that this error is on the server side ? How can I debug the php script ? because it's not my server

Comment: Because you get response from server which says "false". It is also possible that you don't build your json as expected by the server. So basically you need to debug that server to know how it handles your request. If you cannot modify the php then you cannot debug it.

Comment: So i just tested something and now it works, check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access server(php script file url ) and set parems in request and make different debug checks it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there was a simple error that was causing this whole problem. I have used StringEntity and ther I put the "json=" thing. And that's what the server didn't like. Here is the working code snippet:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
    JSONObject json = data[0];
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response;
        response = client.execute(post);
        String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


        Log.i("Response from server", resFromServer);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

    return jsonResponse;
}
```